# Hibernate joined inheritance - Can objects be instances of two child classes?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem with Spring Boot JPA and Hibernate. I have a data structure where classes `Parent` and `Student` are both derived from `User`. They use a joined inheritance strategy so that information like address is stored in the `User` and `Student` and `Parent` contain specific fields. The `Student` contains a `parent field` to know about his parent. They all share the same primary key (that's how Hibernate handles it).

A `User` can be both `Parent` and `Student` if he pays for the product himself. This also works well until the `parent field` of the `Student` refers to an instance of the `Parent`. In this case, Spring shows this error when getting the instances of `Student` from the `Student repository`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set EntityParent field EntityStudent.parent to EntityStudent
```

Are there any ideas what causes this error and how to avoid it? Here is the code, the underlaying database is PostgreSQL:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //Getters and setters for id
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class EntityUser extends BaseEntity {
    //Other fields, constructor etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class EntityParent extends EntityUser {
    //Other fields, constructor etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class EntityStudent extends EntityUser {
    //Other fields, constructor etc.
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "parent_ref",
            nullable = false
    )
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityParent parent;
    //Getters and setters for parent
}
```

Summary:

- It works when EntityStudent.parent refers to a parent object which is not the same as the student itself
- In case they are the same, the error above is shown when querying the students

Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't logically work :

> A `User` can be both `Parent` and `Student` if he pays for the product himself.

The `Parent` and  `Student` are two distinct subclasses, so hibernate wouldn't know which one to refer to if they are both used for the same `User`. What you would have needed is a subclass of both `Parent` and `Student` to bridge the gap but it's not possible in Java. You could solve it using some interfaces but this would complicate things.

You should refactor your architecture so that this doesn't happen.
My easiest solution is to remove the hierarchy :
Just have links (`@OneToOne`) from `Parent` and `Student` to `User`. You would need to get the `User` to access those fields instead of them being readily accessible but that shouldn't take a lot of time to refactor.